# About the performance of jQuery $.each() and bootstrap-select.js refresh()

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 var tenderOfferMode = ... //assignment
 $("input[name='tenderOfferModeAll']").each(function () {
       $("#" + $(this).attr("attr")).val(tenderOfferMode);
       $("#" + $(this).attr("attr")).refresh();
    });
<input type="hidden" id="evaHideAll" name="evaMethodAll" packageId="${item.id }" attr="EVA_METHOD_ALL_${item.id }" value="${evaMethod}"/>
```

Here's the main code, there are about 100 inputs I select(ComboBox). But it costs me 57495ms to finish. And I found it seems the refresh() takes the most of the time.
How can I improve this? Can someone help me?
`$.refresh()`

```
refresh: function () {
  this.$lis = null;
  this.liObj = {};
  this.reloadLi();
  this.render();
  this.checkDisabled();
  this.liHeight(true);
  this.setStyle();
  this.setWidth();
  if (this.$lis) this.$searchbox.trigger('propertychange');

  this.$element.trigger('refreshed.bs.select');
},
```

Comment: What implements `$.refresh()`? It isn't a standard jQuery function.

Comment: Is `refresh()` doing some long synchronous process, eg ajax request? 100 inputs shouldn't cause a 57 second process time otherwise.

Comment: Did you benchmark your code and see that which method takes longer to execute? I'm pretty sure that setting values of 100 inputs won't take that long. It must be `$.refresh()`.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I tested the time cost just now.`$.refresh()` is the main cost(belongs to bootstrap-select.js). But is there another method to refresh the values I can use?

Comment: When do you execute this $.each? Is it possible you do it in an any event attached to the inputs you're changing?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use **for loop** instead of **$.Each**.
2. Also instead of

   ```
   $("#" + $(this).attr("attr")).val(tenderOfferMode);
   $("#" + $(this).attr("attr")).refresh();
   ```

use below:-

```
    $("#" + $(this).attr("attr")).val(tenderOfferMode).refresh();
```

3. In $("input[name='tenderOfferModeAll']") see if you can add context

   ```
   $("input[name='tenderOfferModeAll']", <<context>>)
   ```

like:

```
    $("input[name='tenderOfferModeAll']", '#classcontainer')
```

Comment: There are only 100 elements being iterated over. It seems unlikely that any of these suggestions would make half a second of difference per element.

Comment: I found the real main time cost. The refresh() is belong to Bootstrap-select.js, it is the refresh() takes the most of the cost.

Comment: @user9935396 Can you add a link in the question to the specific library you're using, and mention what version it is? [The library I found with that name](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/methods/) doesn't have a `$.refresh()` method.

Comment: @user9935396 What version? That's the same library I found, and it doesn't have that method at all.

Comment: @duskwuff v.1.12.4, the newest one. I download from the link, it does have. I added the method implement to the question description already.

Answer (score 0):

`$.refresh()` does not appear to be a documented method in current versions of bootstrap-select.

[The documentation for bootstrap-select](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/methods/) describes a `$.selectpicker('val')` method which you should probably be using instead:

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('val', 'Mustard');
```

This is likely to perform better than refreshing the entire element.